# How to select results into an object declared within an object using LINQ/Lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've got a result set returned from a stored procedure and I need to populate the fields of an object from those results. The trouble is my object declares another object that has fields that need populating from the results.

I've got a Vehicle object and declared within my Vehicle object I've got a Truck object. I can't access the fields of the Truck object with dot notation. Simplified code and classes.

```
return dc.GetVehicleList(localDateTimeOffset).Select(p => new Vehicle
{
     VehicleNumber = p.VehicleNumber
     Truck.TruckNumber = p.TruckNumber /* This does not work */
}).Cast<IVehicle>().ToList();

public class Vehicle
{
   public int VehicleNumber;
   public Truck Truck;
}

public class Truck
{
   public TruckNumber;
}
```

**Using LINQ/Lambda how do I gain access to the members of my Truck object declared within the Vehicle object so I can set those values from the result set?**

Comment: Can you please include classes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the inner object along with the outer one:

```
return dc.GetVehicleList(localDateTimeOffset).Select(p => new Vehicle
{
     VehicleNumber = p.VehicleNumber
     Truck = new Truck 
     {
        TruckNumber = p.TruckNumber
     }
}).Cast<IVehicle>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the truck object in the constructor of the Vehicle class and keep your query.

```
public class Vehicle
{
   public Vehicle()
   {
      Truck = new Truck();
   }

   public int VehicleNumber;
   public Truck Truck;
}
```